# Inserting or updating SQLite table depending on id

Tags: sqlite, upsert

I have a SQLite table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int PRIMARY KEY, Name text, Country text, ..., ...)
```

I am getting data for this table that can have the column values changed, except for the `id`. So, I want to insert if there isn't a specific `id` in there, however, I want to update the record with that `id` with the new values.

I have tried this:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO test (id, Name, ..., ...) VALUES (?,?, ....)"
```

This doesn't create duplicate `id's` - which is fine - but it doesn't update the rest of the record either if the `id` already exists in the table.

I want to avoid using `SELECT` for that `id` and check if it is there, then update or insert accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `INSERT OR REPLACE`. This will try to insert the row first and if there is conflict with the `id`, it will delete the old row and try the insert once again.

`INSERT OR REPLACE` has the disadvantage that you have to specify all fields of the row for every "upsert" operation. If this does not work for you, then the only alternative is to do a `SELECT` followed by an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`. You did say that you don't like that, but in sqlite this is not as bad as with other RDBMSs; sqlite is an embeded RDBMS and not a client-server RDBMS and therefore the cost associated with doing multiple such operations is much smaller. Don't forget to wrap the two operations in a transaction though.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid `SELECT` and then `INSERT` or `UPDATE` depending on the result of the `SELECT`. @CL suggests a solution I have seen elsewhere as well: updating a row with that specific `id`, which will work if the `id` is there, and if no update was made, it means I need to do an `INSERT`. But it is still a two query solution. I don't know which is faster though

Comment: I think `INSERT OR REPLACE` is the only one-step solution. May I ask why you you have such an aversion to doing 2 operations? Let me say again, that in sqlite, being an embeded solution, you don't have to pay the cost that you would pay with traditional client-server RDBMSs, as there is no round trip through the network stack, no context switches, etc.

Comment: Not an aversion, just wanted to avoid unnecessary operations and overhead. In T-SQL, I would avoid two operations if I could use one, as performance would be affected

Answer (score 1):

You could just try the UPDATE, and if no record was actually updated, execute the INSERT:

```java
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("Name", ...);
if (db.update("test", cv, "id = " + myID, null) < 1) {
    cv.put("id", myID);
    db.insert("test", null, cv);
}
```